# Tomcat application fails to start after adding CORS support

Tags: maven, tomcat, cors

I have a Tomcat 7 project which works like a charm on my Eclipse-integrated test server, but fails to start on the production server.

It previously worked on production too, but I had to add CORS support, which somehow made it fail.

To add CORS support, I added this to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.22</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and this to my web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If I remove these lines again, it works on the production server, but CORS doesn't work.

The server throws a `ClassNotFoundException` when I try to start the application, which is strange, because the class is clearly there in the .war-file.

The catalina log claims a few .jar-files fails to validate because "jar not loaded". The .jars are all in the .war, so I do not understand why it fails.

Output from the logs:

Catalina log:

```
May 19, 2015 9:10:29 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase stop
INFO: The stop() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/APIMR]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
May 19, 2015 9:10:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/APIMR]
May 19, 2015 9:10:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/APIMR.war
May 19, 2015 9:10:37 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/APIMR/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-el-api-8.0.22.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
May 19, 2015 9:10:37 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/APIMR/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.22.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
May 19, 2015 9:10:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
May 19, 2015 9:10:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/APIMR] startup failed due to previous errors
```

localhost log:

```
May 19, 2015 8:22:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
May 19, 2015 8:22:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
May 19, 2015 8:22:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
May 19, 2015 8:22:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@d45f6a5')
May 19, 2015 9:10:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter CorsFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    <snip>


May 19, 2015 9:10:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter CorsFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    <snip>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634691/apache-tomcat-catalina-as-maven-dependency-for-cors-filter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The server will reject jars which already belong to the servers runtime (tomcat-**.jar, servlet*.jar, ...). Try this CORS filter instead: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thetransactioncompany/cors-filter

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
 <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
 <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This worked, according to my tests. I will accept this answer if it works for those using the application as well

Comment: this web.xml you refer to? is it the one present in tomcat/conf/web.xml?

Comment: Thats usually the one from your project.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but with another filter... Where does it says the server rejects jars? What's the point of providing filters if we can't use it?

Answer (score 3):

In my case adding the dependency did not work. It worked when I added two jars in the tomcat `lib` folder as below:

> cors-filter-2.5.jar
>
> java-property-utils-1.10.jar

Comment: when I oerform the above steps I recieve the below error. SEVERE: Servlet [jersey-servlet] in web application [/SummaryReportApp-API] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Answer (score 0):

Although being an old post, this was so helpful. I cannot be grateful enough for sharing this .. Man you saved me from many more days of struggle.

Just in case someone else will bump into the same issue, here is what I done:

1. Added the maven dependency to my project's pom.xml file:
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thetransactioncompany/cors-filter/2.6
2. Added the filter to my project's web.xml `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file to read like below and restarted tomcat:

```xml
</web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>packages</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/appapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This seem to be working perfectly with tomcat server, 8 and 9. If the changes wont take effect, restart the IDE "**eclipse**" in my case.
Thank you again for the awesome work guys. :)